# How can I check if any element in an array contains a value above 0 using Chai.js?

Tags: javascript, postman, chai

I am currently creating a test on Postman wherein I get multiple values and put them into an array from a loop and then expecting that at least 1 of the elements would be above 0.

```
pm.test("Test if array contains an element above 0", function() {
        var member = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.value.length; i++) {
            var result = jsonData.value[i];
            member.push(result);
        }
         <<test statement here>>
    });
```

if [0,0,0,0] <== test fails

if [0,0,0,1] <== test passes

if [0,6,10,1] <== test passes

Is there a way to achieve this in Chai.JS or in Postman?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add some sort of flag in your code before the chai statement. 
Then you can test the value of your flag.

```
pm.test("Test if array contains an element above 0", function() {
        var member = [];
        var flag = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.value.length; i++) {
            var result = jsonData.value[i];
            if (result > 0) {
                flag = true;
            }
            member.push(result);
        }
         <<test statement here>>
         expect(flag).to.equal('true');
    });
```